# How to get the IP address hit more than 10 times in one minute

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the IP address who hits more than 10 times in one minute and then I have to insert that IP in our database to block that IP address

I have data of all IP addresses and I want to use data to fetch only those IP who hits more than 10 time in one minute

```
$se = "SELECT * FROM session ORDER BY id DESC";
$ss = $connc->query($se);
while ($sss = $ss->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $arraychars[] = $sss['vip'];
}
echo $arrlength = count($arraychars);
$arrCount = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $arrlength - 1; $i++) {
    $key = $arraychars[$i];
    if (@$arrCount[$key] >= 1) {
        $arrCount[$key]++;
    } else {
        $arrCount[$key] = 1;
    }

    //echo $arraychars[$i];
}

foreach ($arraychars as $ip) {
    echo
}

print_r($arrCount);
```

The above code just collected the IP addresses which have multiple entries.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: Can you tell me more about what you think about this and what is a trick I can use

Comment: Sure. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You could realize that with Redis very easy. Due the ttl of Redis keys you don't need a cronjob to clear your mysql entries every Minute. https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis

Comment: Thanks, shelly for the answer, But i have my own function where I collected data and store in database, I just want to do like select data from database and count the hits by IP address and if found clicks more than 10 with in one minute, then store in another table to block that IP address